# Tags related to graduate admissions and the job search

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have a number of tags related to the graduate admissions and the job search. [application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application), [application-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-letter), [cover-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cover-letter), [faculty-application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faculty-application), [graduate-admissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-admissions), [job-search](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-search), [statement-of-purpose](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statement-of-purpose). The tag wikis for [postdocs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postdocs) and [tenure-track](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tenure-track) also suggest they include aspects of the job search.

It seems reasonable to split questions about admissions into graduate school from searches for employment, but I am not sure where [application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) falls into this mix. It is also not clear to me if subdividing the search for employment into categories is really needed, but it seems like we should do it somewhat consistently. I think we should at a minimum re-tag the relevant questions under [postdocs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postdocs) and [tenure-track](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tenure-track) as [job-search](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-search) or maybe even split [job-search](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-search) and [faculty-application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faculty-application) into [postdoc-application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postdoc-application), [non-tenure-track-application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-tenure-track-application), and [tenure-track-application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tenure-track-application).

I am not sure how to handle [application-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-letter), [cover-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cover-letter), and  [statement-of-purpose](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statement-of-purpose). The [statement-of-purpose](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statement-of-purpose) tag seems popular enough that we probably want to keep it, but I am less convinced that the others are really needed (apart from being synonyms).